UNIX socket data exchange between client and server. Due to the message length, it stops
I'm trying to set up a UNIX socket communication for exchanging floats between a client and  a server.
The following tutorial did help a lot and I realized a very simple client python code which sends 4 randomly generated floats and send them to a server. The server reads the 4 floats, sum them up and then it sends the result back to the client. Here the code:
client.py
import numpy as np
import socket
import errno
import time
import sys
import os

def main():

    # Create a socket object
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    server_address = "/tmp/uds_socket"

    print(f"Connecting to: {server_address}")

    try:
        client_socket.connect(server_address)

    except:
        print("Error")
        sys.exit(1)

    while True:

        data = np.random.uniform(low = -10.0, high = 10.0, size = 4).tolist()
        msg = ','.join(map(str, data))

        try:
            # Send the floats to the server
            client_socket.sendall(msg.encode())

            # Receive the response from the server
            received_bytes = 0
            expected_bytes = 16 

            while received_bytes < expected_bytes:
                result = client_socket.recv(16)
                received_bytes += len(result)
                print(received_bytes)
            
            print(f"Received sum from server: {result.decode()}")

        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
                print(f"Error here: {e.errno}")

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

        time.sleep(1)

    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

and here server.py
import numpy as np
import socket
import os

from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)

def main():

    server_address = "/tmp/uds_socket"

    # Remove old sockets
    try:
        os.unlink(server_address)

    except OSError:
        if os.path.exists(server_address):
            raise

    # Create a socket object
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    print(f"Loading the model: {server_address}")

    # Bind the socket to the address
    server_socket.bind(server_address)

    # Listen for incoming connections
    server_socket.listen(1)

    while True:

        print("Waiting for a connection...")
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Connection established...")

        try:
            # Receiving data in small chunks
            while True:

                msg = client_socket.recv(128)

                if msg:

                    data = list(map(float, msg.decode().split(',')))
                    print(f"Received: {data}, with length: {len(msg)}")

                    result = sum(data)

                    print(type(result))

                    client_socket.sendall(str(result).encode())

                else:
                    print("No data")
                    break

        # Finally because it is going to be executed even in case of error when transfmitting a message
        finally:
            print("Closing the connection")
            client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Now... both codes run as expected. But after many runs I realized, that one of the weakness of the code is the expected length of the message sent back from the server. I put 16 because a float is rarely shorter then 16 characters but then I had some cases, where the float was smaller than 16, so the client stucks in the while loop...
How can I prevent such cases?
Since the length of the messages is not known at priori, how to check if the lenght of the message has been reached and the while loop can be breaked?

Send the length first in a fixed-length field. The receiver can read this, then read the specified number of bytes to get the float.

Using a datagram socket instead of a stream might be a better option.

@Shawn it sounds interesting. Any link or example?

socket is very "primitive" object and you have to do all on your own. You have to define  own rules how to should behave client and server. And these rules are called "protocol". And people already created some protocols like HTTP - HyperText Transfer Protocol, FTP - File Transfer Protocol, etc. And often it is much simpler to use modules for HTTP instead of working with pure socket. With HTTP you can test your code with web browser or with programs like postman
